# Compare images for rendering differences (ignoring antialiasing)

Tags: image, compare, imagemagick

I have a PDF file that I render using Adobe PDF engine as well as another PDF rip. I want to try to identify places where they render differently. The problem is that they both render with slightly different anti-alias, color, and very minimal positional differences. I am more concerned with larger difference. I'd like to compare the attached files `match1.png` and `match2.png`. These two should match. The files `diff1.png` and `diff2.png` should NOT match. They should fail as the one has a missing letter. I've worked with ImageMagick's compare, but haven't got good enough results to ignore the slight rendering differences and only focus on the major ones.  I think the below algorithm could work, but I wasn't sure how to read PNG files and compare them pixel by pixel.

[sample image files](https://www.carlisleprinting.com/sites/default/files/article_files/ImagesCompare.zip)

1. compare each pixel in ImageA to the same pixel in ImageB. Also compare to each neighboring pixel in ImageB
2. Find the nearest matching pixel from all the tested pixels in ImageB.
3. Store the color difference of this closest matching pixel as difference index for that pixel in ImageA.
4. Repeat this calculation for each pixel in ImageA.
5. Normalize the difference values to make the smallest difference a zero. Un-normalized values might be (3,8,5,18) and normalized may be (0,5,2,15) or some other type of normalizing function.
6. Then count up how many pixels are over a threshold value, say, 5 or whatever. Then this count of 'bad' pixels could be used to calculate the probability that there is a rendering error in one of the images.

This is just a sample algorithm. I wasn't sure how to process PNG files pixel by pixel. I'd be open to a PHP solution or a solution using command line tools such as imagemagick, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would blur the images slightly to remove any fine detail, then look for the maximum difference. A simple difference metric is [dE76](http://www.colorwiki.com/wiki/Delta_E:_The_Color_Difference#Delta-E_1976). [Spatial CIELAB](http://scarlet.stanford.edu/~brian/scielab/scielab.html) does something very similar (if a little fancier).

Here's an implementation using [php-vips](https://github.com/jcupitt/php-vips):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Jcupitt\Vips;

$a = Vips\Image::newFromFile($argv[1]);
$b = Vips\Image::newFromFile($argv[2]);

$a = $a->gaussblur(2);
$b = $b->gaussblur(2);
$diff = $a->dE76($b);

# output a 500 pixel across difference map
$scale = 500.0 / $diff->width;
$diff->multiply(5)->resize($scale)->writeToFile("map.png");

echo("maximum image difference is " . $diff->max() . " dE76\n");
```

For your images, I see:

```
$ ./measure_diff.php match1.png match2.png 
maximum image difference is 13.739426612854 dE76
$ ./measure_diff.php diff1.png diff2.png 
maximum image difference is 55.040554046631 dE76
```

The 13 in the first pair is just differences in colour rendering, the 55 in the second is the extra comma. It's very visible on the map image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you flicker the two match image (alternately display one then the other and back and forth) you will see that both orange colors are different. It is not just difference due to anti-aliasing at the edges.

So using Imagemagick 6, compare will show quite a lot of change (as red). If using Imagemagick 7, use magick compare.  See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/#compare.

```
compare -metric rmse match1.png match2.png match_diff.png
2304.18 (0.0351595)
```

Here the difference is one 3.5%, but the difference image show a lot of red since every pixel has a different value.

[image]

Another way to see the difference is with -compose difference. The whiter the result the more difference.

```
convert match1.png match2.png -compose difference -composite match_diff2.png
```

[image]

This does not show much different, so all values are only slightly different. But by stretching the dynamic range, you can see where it is most different.

One way to check neighboring pixels is to repeat the compare shifting one image 1 pixel in each direction (using -roll +X+Y) and perhaps trimming off 1 pixel all around each image using -shave XxY. You can do that in a loop and save each result. Then use -evaluate-sequence min to find the minimum (closest pixel values) for each image at the same pixel location. That would be equivalent to search the 3x3 neighborhood of compares. The problem is you won't know which image gave the max result.

[image]

P.S. You can also use compare -metric AE -fuzz 5% . The fuzz value will allow the compare to ignore values that within that percent. This does not seem to be working in Imagemagick 6.9.9.10 but is working in Imagemagick 7.0.6.10.

```
im7 magick compare -metric AE -fuzz 5% match1.png match2.png match_diff3.png
```

219487

This says that there are 219487 mismatched pixels of any amount. Here are where they differ.

[image]